CkEditor 5: How to customize track data plugin
I've a project were we use ck editor track changes plugin to track changes a user do in a given text input.
The difficulty is that ck editor track changes only actually track the changes from user if the plugin is enabled, if you disable the plugin it won't see the changes done in the text. On my app, we have a switch were user can configure if he wants or not to see the changes done, but to achieve this behavior the ckeditor 'track changes' must always be enabled, and if user don't want to see the changes I hide them using css.
For basic changes its working just fine, but I've found two problems which I still don't know how to overcome:

On enter, a new paragraph is created, and user can type into it normally (do not confuse with shift enter which just adds a <br\>). If on edit of this data the user 'delete' this change, moving the two paragraphs together, I don't know how to display this correctly by just using css. Example:

<p><span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:16px;">line 2</span><span class="ck-suggestion-marker-merge"></span></p>
<p><span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:16px;">line 3</span></p>


When removing list items, be it ordered or unordered, the 'li tag does not have any class added to it, so I can't remove/customize it. Example:

<li><span class="ck-list-bogus-paragraph"><span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:16px;"><span class="ck-suggestion-marker ck-suggestion-marker-deletion" data-suggestion="ead61b8424dc2e59b1a0b1e3ef591c082">item 1</span></span></span></li>
<li><span class="ck-list-bogus-paragraph"><span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:16px;">item <span class="ck-suggestion-marker ck-suggestion-marker-deletion" data-suggestion="ec2b4addff4394e8dd209f3bb851f51f4">2</span></span></span></li>
<li><span class="ck-list-bogus-paragraph"><span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:16px;">item 3</span></span></li>

Any idea how I can customize either the ck-editor track changes plugin or to fix this issue by using css?
Note: When saving I save both, the text with suggestions and the text with all changes 'accepted' (by using 'TrackChangesData'). The text without suggestion is correctly displayed, the lines are grouped together and the removed list items are not displayed. I only face issue if I use it on 'enabled but hidden with css' way.
